# Python class for homogenous sets of objects

Tags: python

I frequently find myself creating  homogeneous sets of objects, which i usually store in a dict or list dictionaries.

```
   a,b,c = MyClass(...), MyClass(...), MyClass(...)
   my_set = {'a':a,'b':b,'c':c}
```

On a set like this, common needs are

- returning homogeneous sets from the object properties or methods

  - `{k:k.prop for k in my_set}` , or
  - `{k:k.func() for k in my_set}`
- filtering based on properties or the output of methods of the objects

  - `{k:k.prop for k in my_set if k.prop is blah}` , or
  - `{k:k.func() for k in my_set if k.func() is blah}`
- stringing the first two needs together

At first, this seemed to suggest that i should be using a database. however, i would have to give up the freedom provided by using arbitrary objects as elements.

id like to create a class for this type of structure,(if it doesnt already exist) which fufills these needs with something like...

```
   a,b,c = MyClass(...), MyClass(...), MyClass(...)
   my_set = {'a':a,'b':b,'c':c}
   my_set.prop # fufills first need
   my_set.func() # fufills first need
   my_set[prop = blah] # fufills second need
   my_set[prop= blah].prop.func() # third need
```

does functionality like this exist? or is the need for this object a result of bad design?

### Solution

Following the suggestion of @mike-muller to override the `__getattr__` method i created a class here

https://gist.github.com/arsenovic/5723000

Comment: What you want sounds like just a specialized `list` or `dict` -- so just derived your own subclass from one of them and you won't have to reinvent the whole wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are look for special methods of classes. Have a look  `__getattr__` and `__getitem__`. You can write your own class. Its instances of this class can have  `a`, `b` and `c` as attributes and can do what you describe.

Some thing like this might do part of what you like to do:

```
class DictCollcetion(object):
    def __init__(self, dict_):
        self.dict = dict_
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return {k: k.name for k in self.dict}
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return {k: k.key for k in self.dict}
```

Comment: thanks, i didnt realize that `__getattr__` would be called if the attribute doesnt exist.

Comment: Yes, `__getattribute__` is stronger and will be called even if the attribute exists. You have be careful with this not to get into a recursion. As soon as you use `self.` inside it, it calls itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into cases where I have manipulated big lists of dictionaries or objects, much like you have. Often those objects are pulled out of a database and populated via an ORM, but I've done it with CSV files as well.

I am not sure that my needs are frequent/common enough that I would look for a module to give me syntactic sugar for it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just using sets?

```
my_set = {myclass(...),myclass(...),myclass(...)}
props = {k.prop for k in my_set}
```

While you could create a class that does that mapping for you, it's not obvious to me that this makes your code any clearer than sticking with standard mapping constructs.

Comment: it makes things like this very concise (HomoDict defined in the gist),         `h=HomoDict({'a':'asdf','b':'ZZZZ'})`

        `h[h.startswith('a')==True]` ->
        `'asdf'`

Comment: OK, but that goes beyond what OP is asking for. It's still pretty cool, though.

Answer (score -1):

Following the suggestion of @mike-muller to override the `_getattr__`  method i created a class here

https://gist.github.com/arsenovic/5723000

Comment: Makes a good first impression. Did you try it and does it do what you want?