# Homogeneous lists in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to design a python module allowing access to content of a particular file format. The file is essentially a list of layers (mutable), each of which is a relatively complex object with its own internal structure (not relevant for this question). However, the strict limitations of this file format are that it does **not allow "shared" layers** (i.e., the same data referred to by two distinct layer objects), and that it is **homogeneous**.

I am trying to design a Python API to represent the content of this file, keeping the concepts it represents intact. I would like it to be as pythonic as possible to make it easier for the users to use my library.

*Is there a way to achieve this in Python without providing a non-intuitive API? (i.e., something that would significantly differ from a list)*

*Is there an example of this in Python libraries?*

An uber-simplified example follows.

#### Layer class

```
# an example layer class
class Layer:
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.value = content
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Layer(" + str(self.value) + ")"

# make a list of layer classes (as if it was loaded from a file)
layers = []
layers.append(Layer(0.0))
layers.append(Layer(2.0))
```

#### Operations I'd like to be able to do

```
# altering an element
l0 = layers[0]
l0.value = 3.0

# adding an element and altering it later
l1 = Layer(3.0)
layers.append(l1)
l1.value = 5.0

# removing an element
layers.pop(0)

# iterating over elements
for i in layers:
    print i
```

#### Operations I'd like not to be able to do

I am not sure if throwing an exception is a valid way of dealing with errors of this kind in Python.

```
# the layers list should be heterogeneous, inserting anything else than a Layer
#   should not be allowed
layers.append(dict())

# there should never be two instances of the same Layer object in any
#   instance of the layers array (there *can* be two instances with 
#   the same data, but they should not be shared)
l2 = Layer(10.0)
layers.append(l2)
layers.append(l2)
l2.value = 300.0

l3 = Layer(13.0)
layers2 = [];
layers.append(l3)
layers2.append(l3)
```

---

**Final note:** I am a C++ programmer trespassing into the lands of Python. The final implementation will be wrapping C++ classes in Python, and I am trying to avoid using shared pointers and/or representing the file's data in a way that could not be stored in the file. I am aware of the possibility of using [gettattr and setattr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947035/python-class-for-homogenous-sets-of-objects), but that seems to be frowned upon by Python programmers, and I could not find an example in Python native libraries that would use this method and have a similar behaviour to what I need (which would justify this approach in their eyes).

Comment: Would it be acceptable if appending an object to the list would create a copy, always? You cannot then do `l1 = Layer(42)`, `layers.append(l1)` and still use `l1`; you'd have to retrieve the copy. That would simplify solutions a lot as you no longer need to guard against duplicate references.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That was actually the first solution I proposed (and it is the default behaviour of boost::python wrapping of c++ std::vector). The example I wrote in my question was the example I was given as feedback to that, so unfortunately it is not acceptable (unless I can show an example of this done in native Python libraries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be made by creating a subclass of list that overrides the append method. Example:

```
class LayerList(list):

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id=id
        return super(LayerList, self).__init__() 


    def append(self, item):
        #test if the item is a Layer
        if not isinstance(item,Layer):
            #do whathever treatment you wanna do
            raise Exception("Not a Layer object")              

        #test if the item is already in the list
        if item in self:
            #do whathever treatment you wanna do
            raise Exception("Item already in list")

        #check if the layer has the attr "layer_id"
        if not hasattr(item,"layer_id"):
            setattr(item,"layer_id",None)
        item.layer_id=self.id

        #call the parents 'append'
        super(LayerList, self).append(item) 

    def pop(self, i=None):
        item = super(LayerList, self).pop(i)
        item.layer_id=None
        return item
```

Comment: But layers are also not supposed to be shared between lists.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Absolutely true, but I guess I can just keep track of all of them using a singleton "indexer" (which contains references to all Layer instances inserted into any container). By any chance, is this idea used anywhere in Python libs? (It still doesn't help me on the C++ side, because I am still stuck with shared pointers, but that is not what the question is about :) )

Comment: You're saying that the same layer cannot be contained in more than one list? You could create an attribute to the layer with the "id" of the list that contains that layer, and in the append of the list, throw an exception (or whatever) if the "list_id" of the layer is not None

Comment: @lealhugui Or that, yes, much simpler than my idea.

Comment: @martin_pr: no, nothing in the standard lib has to deal with such restrictions. Lealhugui hit on the right idea though; annotate the layer when you add it to a list, and remove the annotation again when you extract it again. That way it is easy enough to test if a layer is already part of a list.

Comment: And that closes the case then :) Answer updated to contain the exemple of "id" treatment.